# Check if cell in column has same value

Tags: c#, datagridview, textbox

I'm making startlist so obviously I want to prevent that there would be competitors with same start number. I have TextBoxes for input values with *Save* button convert to DataGridView table. Like so:

```
bool CheckFiledIsEmpty()
{
    if (textStN.Text == string.Empty ||
        textN.Text == string.Empty ||
        textSN.Text == string.Empty ||
        textC.Text == string.Empty ||
        textYB.Text == string.Empty)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}

private void buttonSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (CheckFiledIsEmpty())
    {
        string Column1 = textStN.Text;
        string Column2 = textN.Text;
        string Column3 = textSN.Text;
        string Column4 = textC.Text;
        string Column5 = textYB.Text;                    
        string[] row = { Column1, Column2, Column3, Column4, Column5 };
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
        textStN.Text = "";
        textN.Text = "";
        textSN.Text = "";
        textC.Text = "";
        textYB.Text = "";
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Input all information about competitor!");
    }
}
```

I want that when the *Save* button is hit, the former values in `Column1` (start number textbox `textStN`) are checked and if there is same value the error box like: *"The competitor with that start number already exists!"*

Thanks for help and sorry for my English.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your code as below:

```cs
bool CompetitorAlreadyExist()
{
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
        {
            if (cell.ColumnIndex == 0) // set your column index
            {
                // do your stuff here… i.e., compare `textStN.Text` with all values
                // in column start # and return true or false 
            }
        }
    }
}

private void buttonSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (CheckFiledIsEmpty() && CompetitorAlreadyExist())
    {
        string column1 = textStN.Text;
        string column2 = textN.Text;
        string column3 = textSN.Text;
        string column4 = textC.Text;
        string column5 = textYB.Text;                    
        string[] row = { column1, column2, column3, column4, column5 };
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
        textStN.Text = "";
        textN.Text = "";
        textSN.Text = "";
        textC.Text = "";
        textYB.Text = "";
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Input all information about competitor!");
    }
}
```

Hope it might help.

Comment: So I have modified it in some similar way, becouse I want to appear MeassageBox with _"The competitor with that start number already exists!"_ , and with this code I can't see it is possible. I modified it like, that I put your feoreach loops after CheckIfFileEmpty and than like: `if (cell.ColumnIndex == 0) 
    {
     if (cell.Value.ToString().Equals(Column1))
     {
      MessageBox.Show("...");
 }
 else
 {
  dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
 }
 }` , but for some reason it doesn't work. Is it becouse there isn't any row to check? If so, how to bypass that? Thanks

Comment: Made it with: `string Column1 = textStN.Text;
                    var SingleRow = (
                    from Rows in dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
                    where Rows.Cells[0].Value.ToString() == textStN.Text
                    select Rows).FirstOrDefault();
                    if (SingleRow != null)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Competitor with this st. n. already exists!");
                        goto ClearStN;
                    }
                     ... 
                Clear StN:
                    textStSt.Text = "";`